# Spongy brakes/ deeper brake press

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

My hydraulic brake (both left and right) has gotten weaker. I don't know how to say it, but it's like my brakes can now be pressed deeper. My front brake is so bad that it is touching the grips. I got this problem after a crash I had. Can someone help me find a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both brakes are exhibiting the same issue, and the issue had developed in parallel over time it's likely that they just need to be bled.

If a crash caused damage and allowed air to enter the braking system, it's likely that only one brake would be affected.

You should inspect the entire brake system looking for damage. Also check the brake pad wear and sticking pistons.

Answer (score -1):

What brand of brakes are they? If they are SRAM/Avid then they need to be bled at least once every year or they DOT fluid breaks down the internals and they feel like garbage. Another variable could be if they already is air in the line somehow. Lastly, are the brake pads completely worn out?

Comment: The assertion that DOT fluid breaks down internal components seems suspect. Why would changing the fluid prevent that anyway?

Comment: However - from https://www.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/95-5018-015-000_rev_d_hydror_disc_brake_hose_shortening_and_bleed_manual.pdf: 'SRAM recommends to bleed your brakes at least once a year to ensure optimal braking performance. Bleed your brakes more often if you ride frequently or ride on aggressive terrain that requires heavy braking. '